# Python Threading and Telnet unexpected results

Tags: python, multithreading, telnetlib

I wrote a script that telnets to some network equipment and pulls the inventory and places it in a file. I used threading to speed up the script as I have around 160 nodes.  I wrote a function that telnets to each node, retrieves the inventory, writes the output to a file, then disconnects the session.  The script worked great when I had those three steps under a single function.  However, I decided to create a class and break those three steps into different methods.  Now when I run the script, it only retrieves data from the first node in the list.  I need some help figuring out why the script isn't working.

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import telnetlib
from myFunctions import get_node_list_TA5K

class Ta5kTelnet:

    def __init__(self):
        self.tn = telnetlib.Telnet()

    def connect(self, hostname, username, password):
        self.tn.open(hostname, 23, 5)
        self.tn.read_until(b'Username:', 5)
        self.tn.write(username.encode('ascii') + b'\n')
        self.tn.read_until(b'Password:', 5)
        self.tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b'\n')
        if b'>' in self.tn.read_until(b'>', 5):
            self.tn.write(b'en\n')
            self.tn.read_until(b'#', 5)
            self.tn.write(b'term len 0\n')
            output = self.tn.read_until(b'#', 5)
            return output
        else:
            print(f'{hostname} is spare shelf')

    def send(self, command, waitfor):
        self.tn.write(command + b'\n')
        result = self.tn.read_until(waitfor, 180).decode()
        return result
    
    def disconnect(self):
        self.tn.close()


tlnt = Ta5kTelnet()


def inventory(node_names):
    tlnt.connect(node_names, 'username', 'password')
    shelf_inventory = tlnt.send(b'show system inventory', b'#')
    tlnt.disconnect()
    with open(f'{node_names}_inventory.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(shelf_inventory)



#adtran_nodes = get_node_list_TA5K()
adtran_nodes = ['BXR1-NODE1-COT1', 'BXR6-NODE1-COT6']


start = time.perf_counter()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(inventory, adtran_nodes)



print(time.perf_counter() - start)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sharing a single telnet connection across two threads, and there's no locking or synchronization.

There's no earthly way of knowing which order that connect, login, send, read_until sequence will be run.

Each thread needs its own connection object.

In addition, I'd refactor things to derive from `telnetlib.Telnet`, and while at it, to ensure the connection gets closed correctly all the time, make it a context manager with `__enter__` and `__exit__`:

```
import concurrent.futures
import telnetlib

USERNAME = "username"
PASSWORD = "password"


class Ta5kTelnet(telnetlib.Telnet):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.close()

    def login(self, hostname, username, password):
        self.open(hostname, 23, 5)
        self.read_until(b"Username:", 5)
        self.write(username.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
        self.read_until(b"Password:", 5)
        self.write(password.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
        if b">" in self.read_until(b">", 5):
            self.write(b"en\n")
            self.read_until(b"#", 5)
            self.write(b"term len 0\n")
            return self.read_until(b"#", 5)
        raise RuntimeError(f"{hostname} is spare shelf")

    def send_command(self, command, waitfor):
        self.write(command + b"\n")
        return self.read_until(waitfor, 180).decode()


def get_node_inventory(node_name):
    with Ta5kTelnet() as tlnt:
        tlnt.login(node_name, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
        shelf_inventory = tlnt.send_command(b"show system inventory", b"#")
    with open(f"{node_name}_inventory.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(shelf_inventory)


adtran_nodes = ["BXR1-NODE1-COT1", "BXR6-NODE1-COT6"]

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(get_node_inventory, adtran_nodes)
```